# Can't import main swift classes into test target?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, import, xctest

I am trying to test the classes in my iOS app. I am trying to import the target `Pickle` in my app that has all my classes into my testing target `PickleTests` by adding `import Pickle` to the top of my `PickleTests.swift` testing file, but I keep getting an error. 
The error I keep receiving is: "Failed to import bridging header (path to bridging header)" (the path to the bridging header is shown in the error, not the parentheses). 
I have tried setting "Defines module" in my build settings for `Pickle` target to "Yes", but it still doesn't work. I have also verified in the build settings that it has the correct path to the bridging header file. 
 Any ideas as to how I can set up my testing? I am on Xcode 6.3.2. Please let me know if you need any additional info.

[image]

Open the image in a new tab to see it larger.

Comment: You get this error just by adding `import`, without any actual tests?

Comment: @matt That is correct. I can add an image to the question

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is that you just delete the test target and all the test files and make a new test target. Since you've no actual tests yet, you have nothing to lose... :)

Comment: @matt Just tried, same issue :O

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the CocoaPods? I've never used those. - If you ignore the whole tests thing, your app target builds and runs okay?

Comment: @matt Without the tests, it builds and runs fine, simulator and all.

Comment: Well, I was no help at all. :( Sorry. I can't reproduce the issue, but as I say, I've never used CocoaPods and I wonder if they add some complication I don't know about.

Comment: I see there is actually a discussion of this at the CocoaPods github site: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2695

Comment: @matt It does seem to have something to do with Cocoapods. Near the end of the discussion jessecurry talks about a fix which seemed to remove the error!! Now I have a new error about another dependency, but that's another question. Thank you so much :)!!

Comment: @matt If you want to just copy his answer and post it here I can mark it as best answer so you can get credit.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should answer your own question, and then in a couple of days accept your own answer. All perfectly right and proper! And possibly helpful to others.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Many thanks to @matt for helping me with this one!

Right click on the images and open them in a new tab to see them larger.

As discussed on https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2695 the issue seemed to be lying with having Cocoapods as part of the project. The answer near the bottom of the link that solves the issue involves clicking on your Application settings, and then clicking on your Project `Info` (not any of your targets' settings). There you will see your `Configurations` settings: [image]

You will also notice that there are two targets in the config settings, and that your Testing Target config settings will be set to none while your Main Target will be linked to the Cocoapods. The fix lies in changing that `None` value next to the Testing Target to the same thing that the Main Target has: [image]

So now they are both linked to the Cocoapods. Making sure your main target has `Defines module` set to `Yes` in its `Build Settings`, build your project and the error in the testing files should go away.

Also, after I did this fix I encountered another error where the linker was throwing an error complaining about missing a library in my testing target. This missing library was another dependency I had in my project, and I solved this error by making sure all of my dependencies that were linked in my Main Target's `Link Binary with Libraries` in its `Build Phases` settings were copied over to the Testing Target's `Link Binary with Libraries` in its `Build Phases` settings.

Comment: Awesome!! Worked

Comment: Thanks. 
Can you please give some more information, 
1. Do we have to add each files like LoginVC,HelpVC and related model files to test target? `Compile sources` in `Build Phases` should same as main target? 
2. Need to add `Link Binary with Libraries`?
We have **custom frameworks** added in our app,facing issues in accessing main target files from test target.

Any idea/suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

Import Module on top of your test class

```
@testable import myModuleName
```

You can find-out your module name on `Target->Build Settings-> Product Module Name`

Then you can use any of class which belongs to that module. No need to import classes one by one.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do this. You can use [link_with](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#link_with) in your Podfile. In your case you would do.

```
link_with 'Pickle', 'PickleTests'
```

And then `pod update`

Comment: `link_with` has now been deprecated and it's suggested to use `abstract_target`

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, on Xcode 7, import with the annotation: @testable.
Example:

```
import Pickle
@ImportTests
```

Then you'll be able to see the classes in code completion and compiling.
source: https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-xcode-7-unit-testing-access/