# UITests bridging header file is not getting added in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, header-files, xcode-ui-testing

I have recently started testing my app with UITesting which was recently introduced by Apple. But the problem is the UITest is not able to use the Header file which I created to use some ObjC libraries. This is causing the UItest to fail.
I have already tried manually changing the header file name in Target tab under Build Settings still the same error.

[image]

And this is my header file name
[image]

Changed name of header file which should be used by UITests.
[image]

My app is building and running fine but the UITests are creating problem.
Could you please tell me how do I solve this problem?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose Pods.debug and Pods.release configuration for the tests target (if currently set to none)

You can find this setting in the "Configurations" section

Good luck! Let me know if this works :-)

EDIT: There is a extensive version of my answer with screenshots [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30837226/6136459)

Comment: I have already tried first one, doesn't work.
Could you please tell me where to look in the second case with screenshots ?

Comment: Please see the extensive answer with screenshots at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30837226/6136459